# Undergraduate university gave out too much scholarship money. I now know years after I graduated. What could happen?

Tags: funding, undergraduate, grades

Long story short, I was not a responsible young adult and I didn't know how much I had taken out in student loans for my bachelor's until well after it was over. I recently asked my undergraduate alma mater to send me the balance statements for all semesters. They did and I read through each of them.

Academically, I had a bad first year (2013-2014) in undergrad and ended with a 2.5 GPA. I distinctly remember getting physical mail and was told I lost my $3,000 a semester scholarship that shaved down the cost of attending there. With the help of a life coach, I wrote an appeal and had another chance next academic year to get it back if I could get an overall 3.0 GPA.

However, I was awarded the scholarship in Fall 2014, but not Spring 2015. It was also applied in Fall 2015, despite not yet having an overall GPA above 3.0. That semester, I ended up getting a 3.6 and got my overall GPA past a 3.0 at last. I received the scholarship in Spring 2016 and through graduation in Spring 2017.

**Could my undergraduate university potentially find this out if they audit their records and determine I owe them money?** If so, I'm a bit concerned about what could happen since that's upwards of $6,000 that I would owe at the very least (for Fall 2014 and 2015) to upwards of $18,000.

To this day, I haven't had any questions or anything about this. As for why I didn't know about this for so long? I left all of my finances in my parent's hands until my Master's program and was negligent.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- That's how much I have in undergraduate loans. I also edited the post to cut the first paragraph. Better?

Comment: $6,000 is probably a rounding error for the university, so it being caught in an audit more than six years later doesn't seem too likely. Whether they can ask for money back might depend on the jurisdiction.

Comment: @Anyon Idk if this helps but it was a "no name state school" in northern Ohio.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- No, I'm at a different school than my MA, which is also different for my Ph.D

Comment: I edited your post to make it easier to follow. You jumped around in the timeline and I found it hard to read. I think this edit is correct, but feel free to change it if not. I am not sure how you reached the $18,000 number, since by my reading, there was only two semester where it was issued in error.

Comment: It seems to me the last paragraph could be removed and the first 3 summarized as "My academic performance was less than required for my scholarship, but my university credited me the funds anyways and did not take it away. It's been 6 years since I graduated." The dollar amounts don't matter, the GPAs don't matter, the specific years and semesters don't matter. Your level of responsibility as a young adult or role of your parents in your finances don't matter.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I reached the $18,000 number since I thought it could've been potentially gone for good after I lost it if that makes sense. Also, your edit is good. Ty for cleaning it up.

Comment: @BryanKrause Yeah, you're right. In any case, Azor edited my post and it looks good to me so hopefully that helps now.

Comment: My comment is about even after the edit...

Comment: @BryanKrause Gotcha. Your first comment had a point but I also want to keep it this way because I want to knock out any questions others will have in advance.

Comment: $18k is a lot to you or me, but to the university it's small change. It simply isn't cost-effective for them to bother pursuing you for this (which would involve legal fees, potential bad publicity, and potential damage to alumni relations/fundraising).

Answer (score 4):

What *could* happen is as you describe it and you get a bill. I doubt, however, that such a thing will happen after, I'm assuming, is several years. They, perhaps, made a mistake, but there doesn't seem to be fraud on your part, which would change the situation.

If it happens, it happens, but there is no action you can likely take to prevent it. You can, however, make sure that your finances are as in order as you can make them so that you won't suffer more than necessary in the worst case. Hope for the best but plan for the worst. My guess, and hope, is that you will be fine.

Comment: I think I'm going to defer to the legal online groups about this particular matter.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the question you ask, there is the question you do not ask, which is: I think I was awarded too much money from the university, what should I do?

Your question is not 100% clear, but it seems to me that now you are sure your former university gave you more money than you deserved. Even if they do not ask you to repay, can you live with this moral burden (I am not judging, I personally would say "who cares, it's an university accounting problem" but your mileage may vary)?

So you have this potential debt of 18'000$ pending on you.
First, the easy thing: 18000$ is a lot of money ... no they are not. If you buy one new car less than your peers during your life, you will have way more than 18000$ in your bank account. Act accordingly.
Second: the "right" thing to do. In my opinion, you should go full transparent with your uni: you already asked the balance statements for all semesters, ask them if they are all paid.

There is a remote chance that your parents took care of them (did you ask them, since they were in charge of your finance?).

If they did not: 18000$ is a small amount in the US, you can get it by working extra-shifts, or even by working with the Uber&co crap, while living on a tight budget for 6 months: not something I would recommend as your regular life-style, but certainly something you can afford as an emergency...

Comment: Those balances are all paid off. The scholarship and loans I took out covered all of it. My parents helped cover the one semester I lost the scholarship but that was the one and only time.

Comment: can you make a chronological order of your financial issues?
Per each year: do you have any outsanding payment?debt?loan?
Per each year: How much were the tuition fees for each year? How much was your scolarship every year?
If all balances are paid, what is the issue then?